# NextJS: Google Ads campaign event triggered in localhost but not in production

Tags: javascript, next.js, admob, ads, vercel

I have added the script in `layout.tsx`

```
<script
  async
  src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ADS_CONVERSION_ID}`}
></script>
<script
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());
          gtag('config', '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ADS_CONVERSION_ID}',{
          page_path: window.location.pathname,
        });
        `,
  }}
/>
```

In another file, when user submits a form this event is triggered.

```
if (response.status === 200) {
      if (typeof window.gtag === "function") {
        // Fire Google Ads conversion tracking
        // console.log("Sending conversion tracking event to Google Ads");
        console.log("hueeeeeeeeee");

        window.gtag("event", "conversion", {
          send_to: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ADS_CONVERSION_ID}/VvgeCJ6fuvIYEL6kjbkq`,
          event_callback: () => {
            console.log("Conversion event tracked!");
          },
        });
}
```

In the localhost, this is printed in console

```
hueeeeeeeeeee
Conversion event tracked!
```

but in prod which is deployed on vercel, only this is printed in console

```
hueeeeeeeeeee
```